# EntityFramework creates corrupt GetSetter files and DataSources for use in Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Community - SSMS 2016 - Entity Framework 6.1.3 - .NET 4.6

Visual Studio crashes every time when a DataSource from entities is slid onto a WinForm, when the Table used has a relation of any kind to another table.
When the table has no relationships, it can be slid as a DataGrid or with Detail fields, but:
1. All fields will be moved with DataGrid. Many field will not be moved in Detail view. 
2. All but the "Id" field are marked with "none" and are not moved to the Form, unless mart as a field type.
3. Some field like DateTime, DateTime2, int and others cannot be moved because the FieldType selector does not to offer the change.

When examining the Get/Setter files there are (at least) two things I can identify as "abnormal": 
     a) Boolean fields a have question mark after the word bool.
     b) The NOT_NULL is inserted in the wrong place in the line.

Is there a known way to get correct code generated?
Is there a way to get relationships created in VS or in SSMS working with the entities?

I have tested this with a Local DB - SQL Server that comes as part of VS 2015 Community, using Code First from Database and with the EF Designer from Database. I have tested this with a DB I created in SSMS, with the Northwind Database and with a minimal database created from scratch in  VisualStudio; all with the crash and corrupt DataSource files. I have repaired and reinstalled VS and tested it on two different PCs.
The only thing I can think of is that either the template used to generate the Entity Framework is deffective, or the databases, once opened in SSMS 2016 are not fully readable by VS 2015.

I am fairly new to VS  (coming from VSP) and unable to continue until this is solved.
Please help.

The Solution has a database with three tables: Customer, Product and Supplier, autogenerated by VS.

```
namespace EntTrade
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> HireDate { get; set; }
    }
}                                                                                                                                      

namespace EntTrade
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Product()
        {
            this.Suppliers = new HashSet<Supplier>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ShelfLife { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    }
}
                                                                                                                         namespace EntTrade
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Supplier
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Customer will slide from the DataSources Window onto the form (in "detail" mode) all non-nullable fields. Product and Supplier will not, and the program will hang and reboot. All code is system generated (no coding by me).
Hangs every time with this database, with Northwind and with my customers database.

Comment: You need to show us the code. The `bool?` means that it is a nullable boolean.

Comment: The Solution has a database with three tables:

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled Community 2015 and installed VS Community 2013 - Update 5 plus Nuget Framework. All works fine.
Not the ideal solution but one gains time until the bug is fixed.